# Proving Liouville's theorem on $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I want to know if I did this correct:

Theorem: A harmonic function defined and bounded in all of $R^n$ is a constant.

my answer: Let $u$ be harmonic then all the partial derivative of $u$ is also harmonic. By simply applying the derivative to the laplace equation.

Since $\nabla u$ is harmonic we can apply the Gauss' mean value theorem to get:

$ | \nabla u(x) | = \big| \frac{1}{w_n R^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(x,r)} \nabla(y) dS(y) \big|  \leq  \frac{1}{w_n R^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(x,r)} |\nabla(y)| dS(y) \leq \frac{M}{w_n R^{n-1}} $

where the last inequality is from the fact that the derivative of a harmonic function is bounded by $ C \max |u| $.

Then as $R \rightarrow \infty$, we have $\nabla u = 0 $ hence $u$ is some constant.

---

Is this correct? Please let me know if I need to fix or clarify some thing.

Comment: anyone willing to give some feedback???

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $u:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic, then it follows $\nabla u$ is harmonic and 
\begin{align}
\partial_{x_i} u(x) = \frac{1}{|B(0, r)|} \int_{B(x, r)} \partial_{x_i}u(y)\ dV
\end{align}
i.e. then components of $\nabla u$ satisfies the mean value property.  Then it follows
\begin{align}
|\partial_{x_i} u(x)| \leq\  \frac{C}{r^n} \left|\int_{B(x, r)} \partial_{x_i} u(y)\ dV \right|
=\ \frac{C}{r^n} \left| \int_{\partial B(x, r)} u\nu_i\ dS \right| \leq \frac{C'}{r}.
\end{align}
Let $r\rightarrow \infty$ shows that $\partial_{x_i}u(x) = 0$ for any $x$. Thus $u$ must be constant.

Comment: so is my answer correct then?

Comment: I see, the first integral is over the ball. Not just the boundary of the ball...

Comment: @JackyChong we can also use the Maximum principle right?